Json Parser for Protobuf Java Lite
I have recently moved from protobuf-java to protobuf-java-lite, since I faced Duplicate Class Exception beacuse a library I am using uses protobuf-java-lite and I am using protobuf-java. A major downside to this change is that I cannot parse JSON to Proto Objects like I used to.
Is there any library and/or workaround for me to achieve this?
